# Getting error when using concat function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

Why I cannot use `concat` function? When I run my script, this error will appear.

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2. 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

```
update dbo.[1A]
set Organization_ID = concat (Organization_ID, '-meow');
```

Comment: Which Version of `SQL SERVER` you  are using? What is the datatype of `Organization_ID` column ?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008. Datatype of Organization_ID is nvarchar(255)

Comment: Then answer below should work

Comment: i dont know why i got the error :'(

Comment: Try this  `update dbo.[1A]
set Organization_ID = Organization_ID + '-meow ';`

Comment: it's working. thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

`concat` is [available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) from SQLServer 2012,you can use `+` to get the same result

also use `Isnull` to avoid nulls  `Isnull(Organization_ID)+ '-meow'`